# Filter Parameter Logging in Rails - Database Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, parameters

I'm have a method that calls `User.find_by_remember_me_token(token)` to authenticate a user by a token.

In `config/application.rb`, I added `config.filter_parameters += [:password, :remember_me_token]`

```
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_me_token" = 'LktXTXH2YqHqztFgKNedfsdfRa
```

How do I get [FILTERED] for the `remember_me_token` in database queries?

This `:remember_me_token` is sent in HTTP headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `config.log_level = :info` in `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the log level. It makes sense. I probably should change my log level. when I deploy to production.

Answer (score 3):

You can add config.filter_parameters += [:password, :remember_me_token]

Below is the example as am getting [FILTERED] in database Queries

Started GET "/user/abcdef" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Feb 18 15:21:00 +0530 2012
Processing by UserController#user_profile as HTML

```
Parameters: {"remember_me_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
User Load (17.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`remeber_me_toker` = 'abcdef' LIMIT 1
Rendered user/user_profile.erb within layouts/application (17.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4624ms (Views: 457.5ms | ActiveRecord: 17.1ms)
```

Comment: Thanks Sangeet. My problem is exactly at "WHERE `users`.remember_me_token = 'abcdef'. On my installation, it shows the token. From what I see, this is logged into development.log and I don't want it to appear in the DB.

Comment: Ok,.. You can try this.. Add this **config.log_level = :info** in config/environments/development.rb

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6 I use the following techniques to hide a token from various logs and outputs.

```
def authenticate_user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  Rails.logger.info "Authenticating user..."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Rails.logger.silence do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(token: token)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  end
end
```

config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb helps you filter the logs for parameters sent as get/posts but does not assist with headers ( if you log those)

`filter_attributes` helps you filter from the console put when you `inspect` and object. This includes any automatically displayed return result or to_s. Curiously doesn't support custom printers like awesome-print.

I make sure if I serialize a user to exclude the fields:

`render json: @users, except: User::EXCLUDED_JSON_FIELDS`

and finally I just set the method name to return nil

```
def remember_me_token; end
```

which makes any call to @user.remember_me_token return nil

I don't use them for anything except a login event, so I never need to see what a user's token is from ruby. If I really care I can just look in the database.